# I have a node.js command prompt window, how do I run my html locally since I am loading CSV files on it. I also have XAMPP?

Tags: node.js, xampp

I have tried putting my html file in the htdocs within my XAMPP and have been able to create local server through node.js. I do not know how to run my html locally though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking exactly. When you run a nodejs application and access them through the web browser through http://localhost:8080 it is local! Same with XAMPP only on port 80. you can open html files in a browser without needing a server, but that's for basic html.

Comment: I have been creating basic html pages with simple data- just to get familiar with it. Now that I load data from a csv file, I keep getting an error. I understand I cannot run this html on the web now but I do not know how to test my code (with csv loading)

Comment: i keep getting: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.